# Trying to space words using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that is able to space words correctly, however, if something has a capitalized shortcode, it will not work.

what I'm trying to do is turn something like "TSTApplicationType" into TST Application Type".

Currently, I'm using Regex.Replace(value, "([a-z])_?([A-Z])", "$1 $2") to add the spaces to the words, however this just turns it into "TSTApplication Type".

Comment: Much appreciated, that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either of the two:

```
// Details on Approach 1
Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Lu}{2,}(?=\p{Lu})|(?>\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)(?!$)", "$& ")
// Details on Approach 2
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})", " ")
```

See [regex demo #1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cp%7BLu%7D%7B2%2C%7D%28%3F%3D%5Cp%7BLu%7D%29%7C%28%3F%3E%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BLl%7D*%29%28%3F!%24%29&i=TSTApplicationType&r=%24%26%20) and [regex demo #2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cp%7BLu%7D%29%28%3F%3D%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BLl%7D%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cp%7BLl%7D%29%28%3F%3D%5Cp%7BLu%7D%29&i=TSTApplicationType&r=%20)

**Details on Approach 1**

- `\p{Lu}{2,}(?=\p{Lu})|(?>\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)(?!$)` matches

  - `\p{Lu}{2,}(?=\p{Lu})` - 2 or more uppercase letters followed with an uppercase letter
  - `|` - or
  - `(?>\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)(?!$)` - an uppercase letter and then 0 or more lowercase letters not at the end of string.
- The replacement is the whole match (referenced with `$&`) and  a space.

**Details on Approach 2**

This is a common approach that is basically inserting a space in between an uppercase letter and an uppercase letter followed with a lowercase letter (`(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})`) or (`|`) between a lowercase letter and an uppercase letter (see `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) they also have this as well when you try to do `.Humanize()` on a string. This however doesn't preserve casing, but would be another option if you actually had wanted to change the casing.

```cs
"TSTApplicationType".Humanize(LetterCasing.Title); // TST Application Type
```